# Como pegar os dados json com react, fetch e rest api?

Tags: react, react-router

Estou fazendo alguns estudos com o React, e para isso estou puxando um JSON do RESTApi WordPress.

Quando eu coloco algo como `fetch("https://pulsemaker.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/179")` dá certinho, mas quando passo querys como `fetch("https://pulsemaker.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=10-projetos-para-fazer-com-arduino")` ele não puxa os dados.

Comment: Poste o código. Sem código não conseguimos te ajudar.

Comment: Eu  percebi que na URL com filtros tem um `array` circundando o objeto e quando não tem filtro é o objeto direto. Talvez tenha que fazer uma pequena mudança no seu código.

Comment: fica um array sim, mas fiz uns testes e não fez diferença o array, o que reparei é que a query gera o erro (acho..rs)

Comment: Mas o console.log mostra algum erro?

Comment: Não mostra, mostra o erro no navegador mesmo que é
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

Se eu coloco o ID do posts vai certinho, se tento puxar pelo slug, aparece esse erro

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
  } from 'react-router-dom';

class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            post: {
                title: {
                    rendered: ''
                },
                content: {
                    rendered: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var url  = window.location.href;
        var slug = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length -1];
        fetch("https://pulsemaker.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/179")
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => this.setState({'post': results}));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
               <h1>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
                <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.post.content.rendered }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Post
```

Comment: Galera, resolvido! O que acontece é que a API do wordpress coloca um array logo no início quando vc puxa os dados usando slug, isso não acontece se puxar usando o id do post. 

Como eu precisava pelo slug para usar na rota, fiz algumas alterações. Quem tiver dúvida de como usar o React com Wordpress, pode ver o que estou fazendo de testes no meu github
https://github.com/rodrigopulse/react-wordpress